# Zooming in/out in advancedatagrid using ctrl+mousewheel flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

Is there any way to do zooming in flex3. I want to do zooming in advancedatagrid using ctrl+mousewheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch movement of the mousewheel by listening for the [MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_WHEEL) event. The event object also contains a "ctrlKey" property that will be true if the control key is active.

I'm not sure what you mean by zooming in an advanced datagrid, but the above should enable you to implement this.

Comment: The mouse wheel event is not mine exact question ,I have already done that but i m unable to zoom in flex grid . :( Is there any way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "zoom in flex grid"?

Comment: These is a advance grid in flex,see the below link,
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_01.html
I want to zoom this grid,a zoom is an effect if u press crtl+mouse wheel then you will see this page and all its content gets larger in size. I want this in this effect in for grid not scaling but zooming, scaling is not producing the good result.

Comment: Maybe you want to play around with http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleX and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleY in the event handler for your mouse wheel method to make the Flex app larger.

Answer (score 1):

First set `variableRowHeight` and `wordwrap` Properties of datagrid to `True`. then on mouse over you should get row on which row your mouse is currently.

now for zooming a row on which your mouse is, as Christophe Herreman said use `MOUSE_WHEEL` events to increase and decrease contents size of the row. when your content size of row increased, row height will also increased accordingly.

You can use style function for setting styles of datagrid.

```
('http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_01.html')
```

Comment: This is not my question :) I want whole grid maximization not a single row.And I achieve this by maximizing all the size of content of grid but it is not producing the quality result also the text doesn't Large..